# How to get the exact unique value on checkBox select while other checkBox is deselected? (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have created a group of checkBox where my aim is to select one checkbox and get another checkbox deselected.

I have successfully achieved that using the solution from Stackoverflow.

Now, I am trying to get the value of the checkbox on select. The main issue here is that when I select a checkbox sometimes I get the previous value rather than the current value.

Example - When I click a checkbox with label 5, I get 5. Then, I click 10 sometimes I get 10 but more often than not it shows 5. When I go next 15 then my previous value is shown i.e. 10 and so on.

[image]

```
  $("form :input").change(function () {
    var checkboxes = $("input[name='" + this.name + "']:checked");
    console.log(checkboxes.val());
    if (checkboxes) {
      $(checkboxes).not(this).prop("checked", false);
     }
     
});
});
```

```
<form action="#" method="post">
        <div class="cal_box">
          <div class="part1">
            

            <div class="bill_input">
              <label for="custom_tip">Select Tip %</label>
              <div class="tip_btn_group">
                <input type="checkbox" name="tip" id="tip5" value="5" />
                <label class="btn_box" for="tip5">5%</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="tip" id="tip10" value="10" />
                <label class="btn_box" for="tip10">10%</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="tip" id="tip15" value="15" />
                <label class="btn_box" for="tip15">15%</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="tip" id="tip25" value="25" />
                <label class="btn_box" for="tip25">25%</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="tip" id="tip50" value="50" />
                <label class="btn_box" for="tip50">50%</label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="custom_tip"
                  id="tip"
                  value=""
                  placeholder="Custom"
                />
              </div>
            </div>

          
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mrrajsoni/run821g5/3/

Comment: You might want to consider switching to Radio Button. This can be set to allow the User to Only select one item in the list. Check Box allows the User to check multiple items by default.

Comment: UX: you probably want another checkbox before the 'custom_tip' input to explicitly set it custom - otherwise your user can have both tip5 ticked *and* a custom_tip - which should it be?  (I guess you could clear the input the same way you clear the checkboxes)

Comment: Your fiddle, as provided (/3/) is missing `})` so doesn't run.

Comment: @Twisty - I am using the checkbox because I will be having a reset button that will reset the value and don't want to hold any default value that's why not using the radio button.

Comment: [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/famLbz9k/) using radio with a reset button.   Just for completeness.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you so much for this updated version. I can use this now in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is: on the 2nd click the `$("input[name='" + this.name + "']:checked")` contains *2* checkboxes (see `console.log(checkboxes.length)`) but:

- `.val()` will always give the value of only the *first* one.

So tick 15, then tick 25 and `.val()` gives 15.
Tick 25, then tick 15 and `.val()` gives 15 (because it has the lower index)

Fix is to use `this` to get the current checkbox:

```js
$(function() {
  $("form :input").change(function() {
    $("input[name='" + this.name + "']:checked").not(this).prop("checked", false);  
    console.log($(this).is(":checked") ? $(this).val() : "none")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label for="custom_tip">Select Tip %</label>
  <div class="tip_btn_group">
    <input type="checkbox" name="tip" id="tip5" value="5" />
    <label class="btn_box" for="tip5">5%</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tip" id="tip10" value="10" />
    <label class="btn_box" for="tip10">10%</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tip" id="tip15" value="15" />
    <label class="btn_box" for="tip15">15%</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tip" id="tip25" value="25" />
    <label class="btn_box" for="tip25">25%</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="tip" id="tip50" value="50" />
    <label class="btn_box" for="tip50">50%</label>
    <input type="text" name="custom_tip" id="tip" value="" placeholder="Custom" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification and explanatory answer. You also cleared my second doubt of why selecting 50 gave me 50 and then 25 gave me 25 but not the other way round. I will learn more about "this" keyword.

Answer (score 1):

In one sentence, you face this bug **because you are the logging value of your checkbox before flushing other checked boxes**.
To fix this Just put

```
console.log(checkboxes.val());
```

after your

```
if (checkboxes) {
      $(checkboxes).not(this).prop("checked", false);
}
```

It will surely fix your issue.

---

In addition :

1. I would suggest the usage of radio buttons instead of checkboxes as
   it fits the requirement most accurately, i.e. user must be able to
   select only 1 option. If it is purely due to aesthetic choice its up
   to you.
2. One more nerdy comment  you can still output correct value even w/o changing flow code which is using `console.log(this.value)` instead of `console.log(checkboxes.val())`

Comment: This is the correct answer ("logging value of your checkbox[es]") (so +1'd), however, simply moving `console.log(checkboxes.val());` to the end would not have the desired effect as `checkboxes` would already be set and jquery does not do "live" queries.  You would need to re-query (so easier just to use `this` as you suggest).

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".tip_btn_group input[type='checkbox']").change(function(event) {
    var $self = $(this);
    var tip;
    $(".tip_btn_group input[type='checkbox']").not($self).prop("checked", false);
    if ($(".tip_btn_group input[type='checkbox']:checked").length == 0) {
      tip = 0;
    } else {
      tip = parseInt($self.val());
    }
    console.log(tip);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <div class="cal_box">
    <div class="part1">
      <div class="bill_input">
        <label for="custom_tip">Select Tip %</label>
        <div class="tip_btn_group">
          <input type="checkbox" name="tip" id="tip5" value="5" />
          <label class="btn_box" for="tip5">5%</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="tip" id="tip10" value="10" />
          <label class="btn_box" for="tip10">10%</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="tip" id="tip15" value="15" />
          <label class="btn_box" for="tip15">15%</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="tip" id="tip25" value="25" />
          <label class="btn_box" for="tip25">25%</label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="tip" id="tip50" value="50" />
          <label class="btn_box" for="tip50">50%</label>
          <input type="text" name="custom_tip" id="tip" value="" placeholder="Custom" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

This essentially unchecks any other checkboxes, to ensure only one is checked at any time. The User can uncheck their selection as well and you will need additional code for the Custom entry.

Comment: Thank you Twisty for your solution. It works absolutely well. But I accepted freedomn-m answer since I already have the exact same code and have to modify just one word. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Here's your form

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <div class="cal_box">
      <div class="part1">
        

        <div class="bill_input">
          <label for="custom_tip">Select Tip %</label>
          <div class="tip_btn_group">
            <input type="checkbox" name="tip" id="tip5" value="5" />
            <label class="btn_box" for="tip5">5%</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="tip" id="tip10" value="10" />
            <label class="btn_box" for="tip10">10%</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="tip" id="tip15" value="15" />
            <label class="btn_box" for="tip15">15%</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="tip" id="tip25" value="25" />
            <label class="btn_box" for="tip25">25%</label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="tip" id="tip50" value="50" />
            <label class="btn_box" for="tip50">50%</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="custom_tip"
              id="tip"
              value=""
              placeholder="Custom"
            />
          </div>
        </div>

      
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

And here's your JS code

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change',function(){
    var box = $("input[name = "+this.name+"]"+":checked").val();
    if(box){

    console.log(box);
    }
  });
```